# Django nested loops in templates

Tags: django

How do output the following? I want to output the "grid" class after exactly 4 "block" classes. The inner divs are objects returned from a view.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
</div>
...
```

I've tried using forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 with no success.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with the counter method.  However, it looks like you just have a couple syntax errors that are tripping you up.  You probably want `forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4"`, so something like

```
<div class="grid">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="block">...</div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
</div>
<div class="grid">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try forloop.counter|divisibleby:4. The addition of the zero means the loop is zero indexed. By the time you get to the 4th loop the counter will only read 3 which isn't evenly dividable by 4.